# Linux command to find which port a process is running?

Tags: linux, networking, process

Is there a **clean** way to check on which port a linux process/service is running/listening to?

I know `fuser`, `netcat`, `lsof`, etc all are ways to find that, but they return a bunch of other information along with it. Like for example,  `netstat -ltnp | grep -w process_name"` will do the trick, but it returns

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4880/process
tcp6       0      0 ::1:                :::*                    LISTEN      4880/process
```

Also, I want the port on which the process runs and not which process runs on a given port, something on the lines of,

> `magic_command -abcd process_name`
> returns the port number or else nothing.

PS: I have checked the obvious links like https://ostechnix.com/how-to-find-which-service-is-listening-on-a-particular-port/

Comment: What happens if there are multiple instances of `process_name` using different ports?

Comment: Andy, I guess in that case all the ports should be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsof` can be used for this. Here's how the magic_command may look like:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep <your_process_name>
```

You can wrap it into alias:

```
alias magic="sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep "
```

Sample output:

```
$ magic httpd
httpd      9438           apache    3u  IPv4 2087313137      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      9438           apache    4u  IPv4 2087321333      0t0  TCP *:49383 (LISTEN)
httpd      9438           apache    5u  IPv4 2087321335      0t0  TCP *:49384 (LISTEN)
httpd      9438           apache    6u  IPv4 2087345343      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
httpd     23940             root    3u  IPv4 2087313137      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     23940             root    4u  IPv4 2087321333      0t0  TCP *:49383 (LISTEN)
httpd     23940             root    5u  IPv4 2087321335      0t0  TCP *:49384 (LISTEN)
httpd     23940             root    6u  IPv4 2087345343      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

If you really don't care anything but port, some output processing will cut off irrelevant info

```
$ magic httpd | awk -F: '{print $2}' | cut -d\  -f1 | sort -un
80
443
49383
49384
```

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: Instead of using `awk` here, replacing it with `cut -d: -f2` does the same thing. It would result in a simpler method, both in length of characters to type as well as potential maintenance should one return to this line to make changes.  While I have not pitted them against each other in performance, `awk` is a massive tool for this rather simple job considering its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, when /proc is mounted you may be able to obtain this info from

`ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd/`

(fill in <pid> with the process pid)

Comment: This seems to be incomplete. I tried this on my webserver and got `socket:[30753]` and `socket:[30754]`. Please update with how one can find out what ports/connections these correspond to.

Comment: My mistake.  If you have permission to read `/proc/<pid>/fd`, then file paths are present, not socket details.  The `lsof` answer from @Tagwint is better.